# What interface should props extends to have "slot" property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using slot system in React with typescript. The problem is that I can't find an interface, that contains slot as property, so I get an error from my typescript checker:

```
Property 'slot' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IStockProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your use case? It would help to better understand, it's a bit blurry at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to create your own type. It's quite common to need to create types for props (and state) when using React and TypeScript together.

You apparently already have a type that's defined as:

```
type SomePropsType = IntrinsicAttributes & IStockProps & { children?: ReactNode; };
```

You would need to define your props for this component as

```
type PropsForThisComponent = SomePropsType & { slot: string; };
```

...or similar. (Obviously, replace `string` with the appropriate type for the `slot` property.)

Or if you are in control of `IStockProps` and it's appropriate to do so, just modify it to include `slot`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the slot type to your `IStockProps` type definition. Something like

```
interface ISockProps = {
  // ... existing types ...
  slot: ReactNode;
}
```